# Eclipse debug stops on error even if I have try/catch

Tags: eclipse, debugging

Can I make eclipse to NOT stop at errors if I have a working try / catch? I want to make it stop only at breakpoints.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If eclipse stop at an errors in a try-catch block means that you have set an exception breakpoint, so you have to remove it to make eclipse NOT stop.
Take a look at [this](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/views/breakpoints/ref-breakpoints_view.htm) documentation for more information, you ave to remove the Exception Breakpoint.

Comment: Yes !!! You are right. I had a "Null Pointer Exception" error checking that I put when started using eclipse trying to catch it and I forgot it at Breakpoints View so I was wondering why it stops ! I removed it and it's ok now.